# Unit test dynamically added class to an HTML button Jasmine

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, jasmine

I am totally new to Jasmine and trying to learn how to write Unit tests for my components in Angular 4. I am adding a class to the classList of the button on ngOnInit() of the Component. Now when I try to run the test, it says, cannot find property 'classList' of null. This is what I have tried so far.

**Component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
  document.querySelector('.button-visible').classList.add('hidden');
}
```

This is what im trying to do in my spec ts file.

**Component.spec.ts**

```
describe('AppComponent', () => {
 let component = AppComponent;
 let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
 let compiledElement;
});

beforeEach(async(() => {
 TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent]
  .....
}).compileComponents(); 
}));

beforeEach(() => {
 fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
 component = fixture.componentInstance;
 compiledElement = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
 fixture.detectChanges();
});

it('should create component', () => {
 expect(compiledElement.querySelector('button.button-visible').classList).toContain('hidden');
 expect(component).toBeTruthy();
});
});
```

I am not able to figure out how to test. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is the element with the `button-visible` class part of the template for your component? Based on your component code being in the `ngOnInit()` method it seems to be outside of it.

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel - Thats right Daniel!!! The button actually resides on another component.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to run tests when you have a component that needs to look for things outside of it, you'll need to create a test harness that uses your component and has all of the needed items. In your case, you'll need a test component that contains a DOM node that has the `button-visible` class applied.

You can create a test component right in your test spec to use:

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <button class="button-visible">Test Button</button>
    <app-component></app-component>
  `,
})
class TestHostComponent {
}
```

You'll then need to change your test setup to include and use this new component:

```
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestHostComponent>;
  let testHostComponent: TestHostComponent;
  let component: AppComponent;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [AppComponent, TestHostComponent]
      .....
    }).compileComponents(); 
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestHostComponent);
    testHostComponent = fixture.componentInstance;
    component = fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(AppComponent)).componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
});
```

You can then run your test to see if the button in your test component has the class applied:

```
it('should add "hidden" class to HTML elements with "button-visible" class', () => {
  const buttonElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.button-visible.hidden'));
  expect(buttonElement).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I'm looking for Daniel.. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

I came across a similar issue writing unit tests today. I came up with the following solution:

```
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let component = AppComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
  let compiledElement;


  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [AppComponent]
      .....
    }).compileComponents(); 
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    compiledElement = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    compiledElement.innerHTML += "<button class='button-visible'>Test Button</button>";
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create component', () => {
    expect(compiledElement.querySelector('button.button-visible').classList).toContain('hidden');
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```